# Issue mixing jquery, rails, and haml

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm converting an html.erb into html.haml. I have some jquery in an erb which is..

```
:javascript
  $(".level").live("click", function() {
    //..some code
    <% if @milestone %>
      milestone = "&milestone=<%= @milestone%>";
    <% end %>
    //..some code
  });
```

I want to convert the if statement into haml and for that I'm doing..

```
- if @milestone
  milestone = '&milestone="#{@milestone}"'
```

but this does not work and gives me a syntax error on "if @milestone"

What am I doing wrong? Can you not mix jquery and haml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `:javascript` filter (or any filter) code isn’t treated as Haml, so you can’t use things like `- if ...`. However you can use interpolation with `#{...}` inside filters. In your case you could do something like:

```haml
:javascript
  $(".level").live("click", function() {
    //..some code
    #{"milestone = \"&milestone=#{@milestone};\"" if @milestone}
    //..some code
  });
```

That is a bit unwieldy with the nested interpolated parts, so you might want to move it into a helper method, something like:

```
def add_milestone(milestone)
  if milestone
    "milestone = \"&milestone=#{milestone}\";"
  else
    ""
end
```

Then your Haml would look like

```
:javascript
  $(".level").live("click", function() {
    //..some code
    #{add_milestone(@milestone)}
    //..some code
  });
```