# Rails jquery not working on haml view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if there are dependencies that I might be missing as my haml view output is static; the jquery is not being executed. I am new to both rails and jquery and am working on a project. My code is below:

```
%h2 Admin Home Screen
%tr
 %th Vendor
 - @vendors.each do |vendor| 
  %a.accordion-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-parent" =>  "#accordion", :href => "#{vendor.company_name}"}
   = vendor.company_name
  %p - vendor.title

%script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
 $(function()
 {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
 }
 );
```

I am seeing the output but it is not doing anything. What files and dependencies should I look for and include in my project?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue mixing jquery, rails, and haml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408182/issue-mixing-jquery-rails-and-haml)

Comment: Are there any errors in the js console?

Comment: Thank you @PardeepSaini. I'll review the link you posted. 

I have not checked the console, I will review how that is done and will do moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to insert javascript in haml is as follows:

```
:javascript
  //Your code goes here
```

It probably works if you replace

```
%script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
 $(function()
 {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
 }
 );
```

With this:

```
:javascript
  $(function()
    {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to both rails and jquery

Since you're new, I'll explain how you should do it:

---

Firstly, don't include javascript straight into your document. You need to use the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to create [*unobtrusive* JS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var option = function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion();
};
$(document).ready(option);
```

The benefits of this are numerous:

- It keeps your `views` clear of crappy JS
- It allows you to reuse code ([DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
- It keeps you sane by having a central place for all your JS (so you know where to find it)

Your view should have absolutely no JS in it *at all*.

--

For the JS itself, you need to make sure you're invoking an existing function (`.accordion` in your case), and also that you're binding the JS in the right way.

One of the main issues for Rails users is the inability to "bind" their JS to their DOM because of missing the `document` call. The way to do it is to use `$(document).ready()`, or `$(document).on("page:load"...` if you're using `Turbolinks`, to invoke a function which contains your bindings:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var your_function = function() {
   // bindings in here
};
$(document).ready(); // if no turbolinks
$(document).on("page:load", your_function); // if using turbolinks
```

--

**Debugging**

*Debugging* javascript is the main way you'll find out what's preventing it from running properly.

Nowadays, debugging is actually quite simple - you can use the [Javascript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) in your browser. to invoke it, `right click > inspect element > console`:

[image]

This will show you any errors created by the JS. Whilst I can't read your computer, you'll be able to get much more helpful answers by posting specific errors / reports from the console.

---

**Bootstrap**

Secondly, your use of `accordion` may not be correct.

I presume you're trying to use *bootstrap* to achieve the "accordion" type effect:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse... maybe I'm wrong.

If you *are* using [bootstrap](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), you'll need to make sure you've included bootstrap in your `Gemfile` and `JS`:

```
#Gemfile
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap

// -> your stuff here
```

I don't have huge amounts of experience with Bootstrap. It works the same as every other JS implementation -- to get it working properly, you just need to make sure you're able to bind to the correct DOM element, and call the right function.

Comment: I can add to the answer if required

Comment: As always, thank you @Rich. This is very comprehensive. I am starting to work on this.

   - A hard-headed padawan.